# DXUT Configuration

Tags: c++, frameworks, directx-10

This is actually 2 questions in one, but both relate to DXUT.

1. How do you configure a project to use DXUT in Visual Studio 2010? Do I need to add all of the header and source files to any project I want to use DXUT with? Can I just add ($DXSDK_DIR)\Samples\C++\DXUT\Core to my Include directories?
2. Is there a D3D10 equivalent to:

   DXUTSetCallbackD3D9DeviceReset( OnResetDevice ); 
   DXUTSetCallbackD3D9DeviceLost( OnLostDevice );

If not, why?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <DXUT.h>
#include <DXUTmisc.h>

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Reject any D3D10 devices that aren't acceptable by returning false
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool CALLBACK IsD3D10DeviceAcceptable( UINT Adapter, UINT Output, D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE DeviceType,
                                   DXGI_FORMAT BufferFormat, bool bWindowed, void* pUserContext )
{
return true;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Create any D3D10 resources that aren't dependant on the back buffer
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT CALLBACK OnD3D10CreateDevice( ID3D10Device* pd3dDevice, const DXGI_SURFACE_DESC* pBufferSurfaceDesc,
                                  void* pUserContext )
{


return S_OK;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Create any D3D10 resources that depend on the back buffer
// Create and set the depth stencil texture if needed
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT CALLBACK OnD3D10ResizedSwapChain( ID3D10Device* pd3dDevice, IDXGISwapChain* pSwapChain,
                                      const DXGI_SURFACE_DESC* pBufferSurfaceDesc, void* pUserContext )
{

return S_OK;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Render the scene using the D3D10 device
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void CALLBACK OnD3D10FrameRender( ID3D10Device* pd3dDevice, double fTime, float fElapsedTime, void* pUserContext )
{
//
// Clear the back buffer
//

}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Called right before creating a D3D9 or D3D10 device, allowing the app to modify the device   settings as needed
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool CALLBACK ModifyDeviceSettings( DXUTDeviceSettings* pDeviceSettings, void* pUserContext )
{
return true;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Handle updates to the scene.  This is called regardless of which D3D API is used
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void CALLBACK OnFrameMove( double fTime, float fElapsedTime, void* pUserContext )
{

}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Handle messages to the application
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LRESULT CALLBACK MsgProc( HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, bool* pbNoFurtherProcessing,
                      void* pUserContext )
{
return 0;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Handle key presses
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void CALLBACK OnKeyboard( UINT nChar, bool bKeyDown, bool bAltDown, void* pUserContext )
{
if( bKeyDown )
{
    switch( nChar )
    {
        case VK_F1: // Change as needed                
            break;
    }
}
}


int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{   
DXUTSetCallbackD3D10DeviceCreated(OnD3D10CreateDevice);
DXUTSetCallbackDeviceChanging(ModifyDeviceSettings );

DXUTSetCallbackD3D10SwapChainResized(OnD3D10ResizedSwapChain);

DXUTSetCallbackD3D10FrameRender(OnD3D10FrameRender);
DXUTSetCallbackFrameMove(OnFrameMove);

DXUTSetCallbackMsgProc(MsgProc);
DXUTSetCallbackKeyboard(OnKeyboard );

return 0; 
}
```

And when I try to build:

```
1>ClCompile:
1>  Main.cpp
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall DXUTSetCallbackFrameMove(void (__stdcall*)(double,float,void *),void *)" (?DXUTSetCallbackFrameMove@@YGXP6GXNMPAX@Z0@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall DXUTSetCallbackMsgProc(long (__stdcall*)(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long,bool *,void *),void *)" (?DXUTSetCallbackMsgProc@@YGXP6GJPAUHWND__@@IIJPA_NPAX@Z2@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall DXUTSetCallbackD3D10DeviceCreated(long (__stdcall*)(struct ID3D10Device *,struct DXGI_SURFACE_DESC const *,void *),void *)" (?DXUTSetCallbackD3D10DeviceCreated@@YGXP6GJPAUID3D10Device@@PBUDXGI_SURFACE_DESC@@PAX@Z2@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall DXUTSetCallbackD3D10SwapChainResized(long (__stdcall*)(struct ID3D10Device *,struct IDXGISwapChain *,struct DXGI_SURFACE_DESC const *,void *),void *)" (?DXUTSetCallbackD3D10SwapChainResized@@YGXP6GJPAUID3D10Device@@PAUIDXGISwapChain@@PBUDXGI_SURFACE_DESC@@PAX@Z3@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall DXUTSetCallbackDeviceChanging(bool (__stdcall*)(struct DXUTDeviceSettings *,void *),void *)" (?DXUTSetCallbackDeviceChanging@@YGXP6G_NPAUDXUTDeviceSettings@@PAX@Z1@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall DXUTSetCallbackKeyboard(void (__stdcall*)(unsigned int,bool,bool,void *),void *)" (?DXUTSetCallbackKeyboard@@YGXP6GXI_N0PAX@Z1@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall DXUTSetCallbackD3D10FrameRender(void (__stdcall*)(struct ID3D10Device *,double,float,void *),void *)" (?DXUTSetCallbackD3D10FrameRender@@YGXP6GXPAUID3D10Device@@NMPAX@Z1@Z)
```

And here are my VS settings:

```
Executable Directories:
$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x86

Include Directories:
C:\GCC\Source\DXUT\Optional
C:\GCC\Source\DXUT\Core
$(DXSDK_DIR)Include

Library Directories:
$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86

Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies:
d3dx10.lib
d3dx9.lib
dxerr.lib
dxguid.lib
winmm.lib
comctl32.lib
```

When I include the DXUT .cpp files in my project and try to build, I still get linker errors.

```
1>DXUTmisc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DXTraceW@20
1>DXUTcamera.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXMatrixLookAtLH@16
1>DXUTcamera.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXVec3TransformCoord@12
1>DXUTcamera.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DX10CreateEffectFromMemory@56
1>DXUTcamera.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXMatrixRotationYawPitchRoll@16
1>DXUTcamera.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXMatrixTranslation@16
1>DXUTcamera.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXMatrixRotationQuaternion@8
1>DXUTcamera.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXVec3Normalize@8
1>DXUTcamera.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXMatrixInverse@12
1>DXUTcamera.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXCreateEffect@36
1>DXUTcamera.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXMatrixRotationX@8
1>DXUTcamera.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXQuaternionMultiply@12
1>DXUTcamera.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXMatrixScaling@16
1>DXUTcamera.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXMatrixMultiply@12
1>DXUTcamera.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH@20
1>DXUTcamera.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXQuaternionRotationMatrix@8
1>DXUTcamera.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXVec3TransformNormal@12
1>DXUTgui.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DX10GetImageInfoFromFileW@16
1>DXUTgui.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXCreateFontW@48
1>DXUTgui.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DX10CreateSprite@12
1>DXUTgui.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DX10GetImageInfoFromResourceW@20
1>DXUTgui.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXMatrixOrthoOffCenterLH@28
1>DXUTgui.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXCreateTextureFromFileExW@56
1>DXUTgui.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXCreateSprite@8
1>DXUTgui.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DX10CreateTextureFromResourceW@28
1>DXUTgui.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DX10CreateFontW@48
1>DXUTgui.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXCreateTextureFromResourceExW@60
1>DXUTgui.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DX10CreateTextureFromFileW@24
1>DXUTres.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXCreateTextureFromFileInMemoryEx@60
1>DXUTres.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DX10CreateTextureFromMemory@28
1>DXUTres.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXLoadMeshFromXInMemory@36
1>DXUTres.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DX10GetImageInfoFromMemory@20
1>DXUTShapes.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DX10CreateMesh@32
1>ImeUi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ImmGetCandidateListA@16
1>ImeUi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ImmGetIMEFileNameA@12
1>ImeUi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ImmGetContext@4
1>ImeUi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ImmIsIME@4
1>ImeUi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _VerQueryValueA@16
1>ImeUi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ImmReleaseContext@8
1>ImeUi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ImmGetCompositionStringA@16
1>ImeUi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GetFileVersionInfoSizeA@8
1>ImeUi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ImmGetCompositionStringW@16
1>ImeUi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ImmSetConversionStatus@12
1>ImeUi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ImmSetCompositionStringW@24
1>ImeUi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ImmSetOpenStatus@8
1>ImeUi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ImmGetVirtualKey@4
1>ImeUi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ImmSimulateHotKey@8
1>ImeUi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GetFileVersionInfoA@16
1>ImeUi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ImmGetCandidateListW@16
1>ImeUi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ImmAssociateContext@8
1>ImeUi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ImmGetDefaultIMEWnd@4
1>ImeUi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ImmGetConversionStatus@12
1>ImeUi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ImmNotifyIME@16
1>ImeUi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ImmGetOpenStatus@4
1>SDKmesh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXGetDeclLength@4
1>SDKmesh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXComputeTangentFrameEx@64
1>SDKmesh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXLoadMeshFromXof@32
1>SDKmesh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXCreateVolumeTextureFromFileW@12
1>SDKmesh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXCreateCubeTextureFromFileW@12
1>SDKmesh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXGetImageInfoFromFileW@8
1>SDKmesh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXQuaternionNormalize@8
1>SDKmesh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXCreateTextureFromFileW@12
1>SDKmesh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXLoadMeshFromXW@32
1>SDKmesh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXQuaternionInverse@8
1>SDKmesh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXComputeNormals@8
1>SDKmisc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXCreateLine@8
1>SDKmisc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXCreateCubeTextureFromFileExW@52
1>SDKmisc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXSaveSurfaceToFileW@20
1>SDKmisc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXCreateFontIndirectW@12
1>SDKmisc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXCreateEffectFromResourceW@36
1>SDKmisc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXCreateEffectFromFileW@32
1>SDKmisc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXCreateVolumeTextureFromResourceExW@64
1>SDKmisc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXCreateVolumeTextureFromFileExW@60
1>SDKmisc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXCreateCubeTextureFromResourceExW@56
1>SDKsound.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DirectSoundCreate8@12
1>C:\GCC\Bin\GCC.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 75 unresolved externals
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add ($DXSDK_DIR)\Include to your MSVS environment settings. Don't forget to add lib folder also.
2. There is no LostDevice in DX10 any more. DX manages it itself.

Comment: I have the Include and Lib directories added. I've also copied the entire DXUT directory into my Source directory and added that to Include. No luck.

Comment: When I add the DXUT header/source files to a project and try to build I get a lot of strange linker errors:

Comment: What exact errors do you have? It's all very strange for me. Do you add directories through Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->VC++ Directories? Check that application target platform is similar for Libs directory (x86 or x64). Do you use #include <D3DX10.h> instead #include common "3DX10.h"

Comment: I've edited the original post to include the source code and the errors. I also put my VS settings. I didn't #include <D3DX10.h> yet, I'm only trying to set the DXUT callback functions in WinMain so far. I've also tried $(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x64 but no luck (it's Vista x64). Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Never mind. I got it to work. I had to include more lib files in the Linker Input. They weren't there in the tutorial project and it didn't have a problem building. Oh well, as long as it works now.